# Eclipse configure for GIT sparse checkout

Tags: git, github

Suppose I have a `github` repositories with two folder:

```
app-backend
app-frontend
```

now suppose the frontend is written in `Angular11` and the backend in `Java8`. I would like to clone both two folder inside my workspace with:

```
git clone https://github-link/mygit.git
```

Now if I open a backend folder with `Eclipse` and frontend folder with `VisualStudio Code` I have some trouble when I push or pull (especially with `VSCode` I see a lot of modified file that is not belong to `typescript`).

Even if do the sparse checkout I can't manage to configure Eclipse for push and I should use the command line.

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you

```
----------------------------- UPDATE -----------------------------
```

Thank you @flaxel for your response, I updating my question here to better explain the problem:

So I have a repo like this in my `github` page:

[image]

Now, if I do the `sparseCheckout` and put the `backend-project` inside a folder and `frontend-project` inside another one I cannot setup Eclipse/VisualStudio `fetch` and `push` function. I cannot reach the remote folder.

If I download both two project inside a single folder I obtain the follow result:

[image]

Then, importing the `backend-project` with `Eclipse` and `frontend-project` with `VisualStudio` I see, on both environment, all modified files to push.. for Example with VS now I see:

[image]

N.B.: @flaxel in the previous message I said I saw houndreds of modified files.. it was because I didn't put `.metadata` folder inside `.gitignore`.

But finally the question is, is there a way to have a structure like *figure 1* (or more complex with nested folder as I see on many other github repo) and have this folder separate on workspace and manage it **INDIPENDENTLY** with common `git` operation via `bash` or environment plugin (`EGIT` for example)?

Comment: Which files do you modify? Are they not only files from VSCode or Eclipse? If so, you can simply add them to the .gitignore file.

Comment: I did a single push with one java file and now, when I open VSCode I have about 185 untracked (or changed) files on the git tab of my VS workspace.

Comment: Are the files all in one folder? What is it called? Can you upload a picture of the files or give some names?